# Can't count number of objects

Tags: java

I built a program that has this method and I also want 
to count the number of objects I created. But after running the program. It said that there are 0 objects being created. 
Can anyone know why this is not correct? It should say that there
are 4 objects being created. 
    Here is my codes:

```
    /**
     This program implements code for a Circle class,
     which has a radius field, set and
     get methods, and a getArea method.
     Author: Michael Wu.
    */

    public class Circle
    {
        private double radius;
        private static int numCircles;

        public Circle(double radius)
        {
            this.radius = radius;
        }

        //SetRadius method,sets radius.
        public void setRadius(double radius)
        {
            this.radius = radius;
        }

        //GetRadius method; returns radius.
        public double getRadius()
        {
            return radius;
        }

        //Constructor increments numbers of circles.
        public Circle()
        {
            numCircles++;
        }

        //Copy constuctor.
        public Circle(Circle c3)
        {
            radius = c3.radius;
        }

        //GetNumbercircles method; get number of circles.
        public int getNumCircles()
        {
            return numCircles;
        }

        //Copy method, copy objects.
        public Circle copy()
        {
            Circle copyObject = new Circle(radius);

            return copyObject;
        }

        //Call the getArea method.
        public double getArea()
        {
            return radius*radius*Math.PI;
        }
    }

    /**
     This program created several circle objects and then their areas and radius will be displayed on the screen.
     Author: Michael Wu.
    */

    public class CircleDemo
    {
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            int numCircles;

            //Create two circle objects.
            Circle c1 = new Circle(3.7);
            Circle c2 = new Circle(5.9);
            Circle c3 = new Circle(c1);

            //Declare a circle object. 
            Circle c4;

            //Make c3 reference a copy of a object refferenced by c1.
            c4 = c2.copy();

            //Display outputs.
            System.out.println("The radius for circle1 is "+ c1.getRadius());
            System.out.println("The area for circle1 is "+ c1.getArea());

            System.out.println("The radius for circle2 is "+ c2.getRadius());
            System.out.println("The area for circle2 is "+ c2.getArea());

            System.out.println("The radius for circle3 is "+ c3.getRadius());
            System.out.println("The area for circle3 is "+ c3.getArea());

            System.out.println("The radius for circle4 is "+ c4.getRadius());
            System.out.println("The area for circle4 is "+ c4.getArea());

            //Get the number of circles.
            numCircles = c1.getNumCircles();

            System.out.println("There are "+numCircles+" objects being created.");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The constructors you're calling to create the objects (the ones that take a parameter) don't call the no-arg constructor that increments the counter. Try:

```
public Circle(double radius)
{
    this();
    this.radius = radius;
}

public Circle(Circle c3)
{
    this();
    radius = c3.radius;
}
```

You have to explicitly call `this()` otherwise the constructors will implicitly call `super()`, which in your case is the `Object` constructor.

Answer (score 6):

You only increment `numCircles` when you call the `Circle` constructor with no arguments.  But you never call that specific constructor; you call the other constructors.

Increment `numCircles` on all constructors.

Incidentally, because `numCircles` is `static`, the method `getNumCircles` that returns this number should also be `static`, and you could invoke it as follows: `Circle.getNumCircles()`.

Comment: Or call `this()` at the start of all the other constructors.

Comment: @ILMTitan You're right; in this case, calling `this()` would work too.

Answer (score 2):

As other answers have mentioned, you should call your zero argument constructor first via `this()` in each of your constructors in order to ensure that it is executed.  Currently, your code does not invoke the code in the zero argument constructor since it is never called directly, nor is it called when your other constructors are invoked.

Alternatively, you could instead add an inline initialization block below your declaration, e.g:

```
private static int numCircles = 0;
// Increment numCircles for every object constructed.
{
    numCircles++;
}
```

This is less standard, and possibly worse practice, but it will automatically ensure its execution without needing to increment numCircles in any constructor.

Comment: +1 for use of initialisation block. I think it's good here as it's a separate concern.

Answer (score 0):

u should initialize `numCircles` with 0 and increase it on each constructor call, especially because u have multiple constructors u have to keep track that they are all incrementing `numCircles`. U can call one constructor from the inside of the other, so u may not add equal statements to each constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Move your code 'numCircles++;' to Circle(double radius) constructor. Circle() is not called when you create circle object

```
public Circle(double radius)
{
    this.radius = radius;
    numCircles++;
}
```